# Kivy nested IDs

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm trying to create a customer management software, so I need to create a `GUI`. I chose `Kivy` because it's Open Source and `LGPL`.

This software is meant to have multiple panels, so I need to have `ID`'s to access widgets in each panel. I created `Kivy` rules in kv language, but when I nest a class is another one, I can't access the `ID`'s. Below an example code:

*LayoutTestApp.py* :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class SkipperList(GridLayout):
    pass


class TestPanel(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestPanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print "TestPanel ids:", self.ids


class MasterPanel(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class NjordApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NjordApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        root = MasterPanel()
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = NjordApp()
    application.run()
```

*njord.kv*

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<MasterPanel>
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Skippers'
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 10
            spacing: 10
            TestPanel:

<TestPanel>:
    id: SkipperPanelId
    BoxLayout:
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Label:
                text: 'List des mecs'
                size_hint: 1, 0.09
            Button:
                id: button_up
                size_hint: 1, 0.08
                text:'/\\'
            Button:
                id: button_down
                size_hint: 1, 0.08
                text:'\/'
```

When I launch the software, the print only return `{}`.
Can someone tell me how to access button_up `ID` for example ?
Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't see the ids is because you are printing in the *constructor* of `TestPanel`.  It hasn't finished being created yet, let alone have anything added to it.  If you print the ids after the GUI has been created (ie, from a button press) then you will see the ids:

```
class TestPanel(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestPanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print "TestPanel ids:", self.ids

    def test(self, *x):
        print self.ids


...

        Button:
            id: button_up
            size_hint: 1, 0.08
            text:'/\\'
            on_press: root.test()
```

output:

```
{'button_down': <WeakProxy to <kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x7f63159052c0>>, 'button_up': <WeakProxy to <kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x7f63158f3738>>}
```

Comment: Great thank you, I knew I was doing something wrong.
Now, how do I know that the object has finished being created ? If for example I want to initialize the text of my button to something upon the creation of TestPanel, could I do that ?
Thanks again for your answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you not just set the text to what you want to initialize it to in kv?  If you want to set it dynamically you can use a ```StringProperty``` and bind the text of the button to that property.  In this case the button doesn't need to be created before you set the label (just set the property and kivy will take care of updating the button after it's created)